Ansible run role with specific tag defined in playbook
Usecase
I have a playbook test.yml in which multiple roles are executed:
- name: 'create cnames'
  hosts: sysops_setup_grafana_server

  roles:
  - role: test.sysops.vcenter_vm
  - role: test.sysops.certificate

Within the role test.sysops.vcenter_vm there are multiple included tasks:
---
- name: 'configure active directory'
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: ad.yml
  tags:
  - 'vcenter_vm'
  - 'vcenter_vm:ad:computer'

- name: 'configure eam'
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: eam.yml
  tags:
  - 'vcenter_vm'
  - 'vcenter_vm:eam'
  - 'vcenter_vm:eam:service_ou'
  - 'vcenter_vm:eam:groups'


- name: 'configure dns'
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: dns.yml
  tags:
  - 'vcenter_vm'
  - 'vcenter_vm:dns'
  - 'vcenter_vm:dns:arecords'
  - 'vcenter_vm:dns:cnames'
  - 'vcenter_vm:dns:cleanup'

Problem
I want the playbook test.yml to run the role test.sysops.vcenter_vm with the tag vcenter_vm:dns:cnames, without explicitly setting the tags in the ansible-playbook test.yml --tags 'vcenter_vm:dns:cnames' command.
TAGS_RUN
I know that the TAGS_RUN configuration settings exists. But as I am working in a shared environment, I do not want to change anything in the ansible.cfg file.

Are you almost asking for "I want the playbook to run the role with the tag without explicitly setting the tags"? Whereby it is possible to "read" or Access tags at run time, it is not possible to set or change them later.

@U880D kind of, yes. I tried the ansible_run_tags approach and it worked just fine. Thanks a lot!


How to define tags during  playbook run?

Whereby it is possible to Access tags at run time or read the variable content, it is not possible to set or change them later.

I know that the TAGS_RUN configuration settings exists. But as I am working in a shared environment, I do not want to change anything in the ansible.cfg file.

Without changing the config file every time, or have multiple config files in place, there is only the following option. A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      ansible_run_tags: "dynamic_after"

  - debug:
      msg: "Show given tags: {{ ansible_run_tags }}"
    tags: always

called via
ANSIBLE_RUN_TAGS='static_before' ansible-playbook tags.yml

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'Show given tags: [''static_before'']'

But still one need to define the tags before on CLI. Otherwise Previewing the results of using tags via --list-tasks wouldn't be possible.
ANSIBLE_RUN_TAGS='static_before' ansible-playbook tags.yml --list-tasks

playbook: tags.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost        TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug     TAGS: [always]

Documentation

Selecting or skipping tags when you run a playbook

Ansible runs or skips all tasks with tags that match the tags you pass at the command line.


Previewing the results of using tags

These command-line flags have one limitation: they cannot show tags or tasks within dynamically included files or roles. See Comparing includes and imports: dynamic and static reuse for more information on differences between static imports and dynamic includes.



